# Twilio IP Messaging token issue

Tags: ios, twilio

I'm setting up an iOS app to use the IP Messaging and video calling apis. I'm able to connect, create channels and setup a video call if I manually create hard-coded tokens for the app. However, if I want to use the PHP server (as described here https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/quickstart-ios) then I always get an error and it can't connect anymore.

I'm attaching a screenshot of what I see when I hit the http://localhost:8080 address which seems to produce a 500 Internal error on this URL: https://cds.twilio.com/v2/Streams

Thanks so much!

[image]

Comment: Seems like a problem with the server component of your app . Can you double check if the server app is properly setup , specifically if the all the values in "config.example.php" have been setup and then the file renamed to config.php ?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've checked the config.php file several times, I even re-generated API keys and created a new service id but all without success.  Also, when I hit the token.php directly I do get back a JSON back with a token, something like this: {"identity":"DaftAnnaWarsaw","token":"ey....M"} so it seems like somehow a token is being generated. And, when I look at the terminal log from the PHP server I see this line often:  Invalid request (Unexpected EOF).  Any more clues?

Answer (score 1):

After much time spent on this I decided to [try the node backend instead](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/quickstart-ios#server) - under other server-side languages of the PHP and I have it running in 2 minutes! I used the exact same credentials as the ones that I was using on the PHP config file so either my PHP environment has something strange or the PHP backend needs some fixing. In any case, I'm able to move forward using the node backend, so if you run into the same issue just try node instead of PHP. woohoo!